# Laravel 5 REST client CRUD

Tags: php, rest, laravel, laravel-5

Is there a way in Laravel 5 to do a CRUD using REST? I have a REST API already using CodeIgniter and I want my Laravel application to communicate with it.

So let's say I have this url to get all gender: http://api.local/api/api_gender/gender

In my controller, it seems I can do something like this:

```
$results = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://api.local/api/api_gender/gender/'));
```

But I dont know if this is the right way to do it.

Now, how could I do it if I want to add a new gender in Laravel? In CI, I could simply use Phil's rest library and just use `$this->rest->put('http://api.local/api/api_gender/gender/', $parameters)`

Comment: **bump**. any updates?

Comment: I have the same issue. I know that [Unirest](https://github.com/Mashape/unirest-php) can handle it, but I can't find any practical code.

Comment: I stumbled upon this [link](http://support.ladesk.com/061754-How-to-make-REST-calls-in-PHP?r=1) It seems that I have to create my own REST client using cURL. Or is there a package already that does this? I saw nathanmac's package [link](https://github.com/nathanmac/laravel-restclient) but it just supports Laravel 4.*

Comment: I'm searching into [Packalyst](http://packalyst.com/)

Comment: There might be something here in [Packagist](https://packagist.org/) too

Comment: [This](https://packagist.org/packages/enathan/laravel-http-rest-client) looks promising.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would use [Guzzle](http://guzzle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/), a very popular, flexible HTTP client for PHP. As far as I know, it is one of the most used packages to make HTTP requests in PHP.

```
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();

$client->put('http://api.local/api/api_gender/gender/', ['json' => ['foo' => 'bar']]);
// or
$client->put('http://api.local/api/api_gender/gender/', ['query' => ['foo' => 'bar']]);
```

Comment: Great!! Just what I needed!