# Does Laravel use REST?

Tags: php, html, rest, laravel

I'm learning the basics of Laravel and Rest in an attempt to improve my web development. The routing file in Laravel makes use of GET, PUT, POST and DELETE - does this make Laravel RESTful?

Comment: You should have to see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/28984675/3081659

Comment: Laravel by itself isn't RESTful - it's a framework. Out of the box it doesn't really "do" anything, but it does provide an enormous amount of helper classes and libraries that make it easier to write a RESTful API, as do many other frameworks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel 5 REST client CRUD](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28793403/laravel-5-rest-client-crud)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Laravel can be used to create RESTful applications but just because Laravel router being able to distinguish between  GET, PUT, POST and DELETE doesn't make the framework RESTful itself.For example, one can use Laravel to create an application which only use GET and POST. Laravel is a PHP framework. REST is a web service architecture. You can use any web developing language like PHP, Ruby, Python or ASP.NET or web frameworks of those languages  to create a RESTful web service. Finally, just because you use Laravel dosen't make your application RESTful