# How to send data to an API in PHP Laravel?

Tags: php, json, laravel

I'm new to Laravel framework so I'm having a hard time to do something very trivial. The main idea is to contact an API and get its response. Below is my function where I'm having error,

```
public function verification($id=null){
        try{
             $res = $client->createRequest('POST','http://35.161.181.102/api/socialverify/linkedin',['headers' => $headers , 'body' => $urlclean]);  
             $res= $client->send($res);  
         }catch(\GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException $e) {
             \Log::info($e->getMessage());
             \Log::info($e->getCode());
             \Log::info($e->getResponse()->getBody()->getContents());
         }
    }
```

When I run the above function I'm getting the error shown below,

```
Illegal string offset 'id'
```

Any pointers on what I'm doing wrong and how can I solve it.

Any help is appreciated. Thank in advance.

Comment: What do you see in your `/storage/logs/laravel.log`?

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28793403/laravel-5-rest-client-crud

Comment: So it's an error returned from the web service? So it's not status 200 right?

Comment: Yes it's from webservice and the status it returns is 500

Comment: So I afraid nothing much can be done here? Need to either check that you have submitted the correct payload, or check with the author of the web service?

Answer (score 1):

What do you see in your `/storage/logs/laravel.log`?

I assume `Client` is `Guzzle Client` and by default Guzzle throws `RequestException` whenever there is a request issue. [See Documentation](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/quickstart.html?highlight=requestexception#exceptions). So why not try to do this and see what's the error responded from Guzzle:

```
try {
    $response = $client->post('http://link-to-my-api', array(
        'headers' => array('Content-type' => 'application/json'),
        'body' => $data
    ));
    $response->send(); 
}catch(\GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException $e) {
    \Log::info($e->getMessage());
    \Log::info($e->getCode());
    \Log::info($e->getResponse()->getBody()->getContents());
}
```

And check your `/storage/logs/laravel.log` to see the logs being printed.

Comment: I kept it in the try-catch and I'm getting the error about Illegal offset. I have updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this way:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http;

   $response = Http::withHeaders($header)
        ->post($url, [
             $data
        ]);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).